# Writing ObservableCollection to json file

Tags: c#, json, observablecollection

I'm writing a WPF App and I'm saving my data in a JSON file.
The problem is that I have an ObservableCollection in my Object to serialize and every time I write the file it doesn't write the ObservableCollection!(The other variables are written correctly) and I've checked the collection and it's not null.

```
class VarGlob
{
    private int demandeCount;
    private int etatDemandeObj;
    private ObservableCollection<Chapitre> dataContextObj;
    private static ObservableCollection<Chapitre> dataContext;
    private static int numBonDeCom;

    public int DemandeCount { get => demandeCount; set => demandeCount = value; }
    public int EtatDemandeObj { get => etatDemandeObj; set => etatDemandeObj = value; }
    public static ObservableCollection<Chapitre> DataContext { get => dataContext; set => dataContext = value; }
    internal ObservableCollection<Chapitre> DataContextObj { get => dataContextObj; set => dataContextObj = value; }

    public VarGlob()
    {
        DemandeCount = Demande.DemandeCount;
        EtatDemandeObj = Demande.EtatDemande;
        DataContextObj = DataContext;
    }
    public static void initVarGlob()
    {
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"./VarGlob.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            VarGlob varGlob = (VarGlob) serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(VarGlob));
            Demande.DemandeCount = varGlob.DemandeCount;
            Demande.EtatDemande = varGlob.EtatDemandeObj;
            if (varGlob.EtatDemandeObj == 0)
            {
                VarGlob.DataContext = Chapitre.GetChapitres("FirstDB");
            }else
                VarGlob.DataContext = varGlob.DataContextObj;

        }
    }
    public static void saveVarGlob()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@".\VarGlob.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new VarGlob()));
    }
```

and here is the file content :

```
{"DemandeCount":0,"EtatDemandeObj":0}
```

edit : I've forgot to mention that when i write the ObservableCollection alone to another file it works here's the code:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"./MainDataContext"+ ".json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataContext));
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your `saveVarGlob()` function is writing a new `VarGlob()` object to the json file, which means your `initVarGlob()` function is never ran. Looking at your code, it looks like you need that function to run to gather data into your collection before writing to the json file.

Comment: `saveVarGlob` shouldn't be `static`, that way you can do `File.WriteAllText(@".\VarGlob.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)));`

Comment: @Tronald the initVarGlob() is only used to initialize data I'm bypassing it in my tests by setting the VarGlob.DataContext manually.@Ron Thank you for your advice I've declared the function to bypass this problem until I get a final fix( I'm writing to another file the observablecollection alone)